# Microsoft naming convention

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

Microsoft favors PascalCase whenever working with classes and namespaces.
My question is why XML is: `System.Xml` Whilst IO is: `System.IO`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx. "Uppercase
All letters in the identifier are capitalized. For example:
IO"

Comment: "A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters are capitalized"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about design decisions, which is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [capitalization rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0):

> A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters
>   are capitalized, as shown in the following identifier: `IOStream`